# Create mongoose schema for object which has an heterogeneous array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Given the object:

```
let defaultProfile = {
      codecs: [
        {
          odatatype: '#Microsoft.Media.H264Video',
          keyFrameInterval: 'PT2S',
          layers: [
            {
              odatatype: '#Microsoft.Media.H264Layer',
              profile: 'Main',
              level: '3.1',
              bufferWindow: 'PT5S',
              bFrames: 3,
              referenceFrames: 3,
              adaptiveBFrame: true,
              frameRate: '24000/1001',
              bitrate: 2940000,
              maxBitrate: 2940000,
              width: '1280',
              height: '720',
              label: '1280x720'
            },
            {
              odatatype: '#Microsoft.Media.H264Layer',
              profile: 'Main',
              level: '3.1',
              bufferWindow: 'PT5S',
              bFrames: 3,
              referenceFrames: 3,
              adaptiveBFrame: true,
              frameRate: '24000/1001',
              bitrate: 320000,
              maxBitrate: 320000,
              width: '320',
              height: '180',
              label: '320x180'
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          odatatype: '#Microsoft.Media.AacAudio',
          channels: 2,
          samplingRate: 48000,
          bitrate: 128000,
          profile: 'AacLc',
          label: 'aacAudio'
        }
      ]
    }
```

which contains an heterogeneous array, is there any legitimate way to create a mongoose Schema for it?

I have tried

```
let amsProfileSchema =   {
      id: { type: String },
      codecs: [
        {
          odatatype: { type: String, enum: ['#Microsoft.Media.H264Video'] }, 
          keyFrameInterval: { type: String },
          layers: [
            {
              // https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/rest/api/media/transforms/createorupdate#h264layer
              odatatype: { type: String, enum: ['#Microsoft.Media.H264Layer'] }, 
              profile: { type: String, enum: ['Baseline', 'Main', 'High', 'High422', 'High444'] },
              level: { type: String },
              bufferWindow: { type: String },
              bFrames: { type: Number },
              referenceFrames: { type: Number },
              adaptiveBFrame: { type: Boolean },
              frameRate: { type: String },
              bitrate: { type: Number, required: true },
              maxBitrate: { type: Number },
              width: { type: String },
              height: { type: String },
              label: { type: String }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          // https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/rest/api/media/transforms/createorupdate#aacaudio
          odatatype: { type: String, enum: ['#Microsoft.Media.AacAudio'] },
          channels: { type: Number },
          samplingRate: { type: Number },
          bitrate: { type: Number },
          profile: { type: String, enum: ['AacLc', 'HeAacV1', 'HeAacV2'] },
          label: { type: String }
        }
      ]
    }
```

But when I try to use it like so:

```
    const mongooseSchema = mongoose.Schema(Object.assign({}, amsProfileSchema))

    let AMSProfileModel = mongoose.model('ams', mongooseSchema)
    let amsProfileInstance = new AMSProfileModel(defaultProfile)
```

although the first codec array entry works, the 2nd does not. As `amsProfileInstance` I get :

```
{
  _id: '5cc06f897b2e490011a71c00',
  codecs: [
    {
      _id: '5cc06f897b2e490011a71c02',
      odatatype: '#Microsoft.Media.H264Video',
      keyFrameInterval: 'PT2S',
      layers: [
        {
          _id: '5cc06f897b2e490011a71c07',
          odatatype: '#Microsoft.Media.H264Layer',
          profile: 'Main',
          level: '3.1',
          bufferWindow: 'PT5S',
          bFrames: 3,
          referenceFrames: 3,
          adaptiveBFrame: true,
          frameRate: '24000/1001',
          bitrate: 2940000,
          maxBitrate: 2940000,
          width: '1280',
          height: '720',
          label: '1280x720'
        },           
        {
          _id: '5cc06f897b2e490011a71c03',
          odatatype: '#Microsoft.Media.H264Layer',
          profile: 'Main',
          level: '3.1',
          bufferWindow: 'PT5S',
          bFrames: 3,
          referenceFrames: 3,
          adaptiveBFrame: true,
          frameRate: '24000/1001',
          bitrate: 320000,
          maxBitrate: 320000,
          width: '320',
          height: '180',
          label: '320x180'
        }
      ]
    },
    { _id: '5cc06f897b2e490011a71c01', 
      odatatype: '#Microsoft.Media.AacAudio', 
      layers: [] 
    }
  ]
}
```

which looks like it is (maybe) forcing the 2nd aray entry into the format of the first one?

Or did I make some other daft mistake that I can't see?

Or is my whole approach wrong - if so, what is the right one? (I want to save these objects to a MongoDb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i can suggest you is go with

**strict:False**

what strict:True(default) is doing?

The strict option, (enabled by default), ensures that values passed to our model constructor that were not specified in our schema do not get saved to the db.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict

Comment: That is 99% of my answer. I am still getting an empty "layers" array on the 2nd codec, but I *think* that might be ok. What I don't understand is that the fields *are* defined in the schema - But maybe you simply can't specify a schema as I have done, with an array where there are a fixed number of entries, but those entries are of different types (I can certainly see the logic, but would have expected to get some sort of error when creating the schema!)

Comment: the reason why you are not getting is error is because of strict:false.what strict:false is doing is that it will validate the field only if the keys are same otherwise it will ignore the validation and store it as it is.

Comment: Sorry, to be clear, I meant, when I do NOT have *strict:false* I do not get any errors. But perhaps that is just how it is.

Answer (score 1):

You are likely looking for the mixed schema type. Here is the docs page about it.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#mixed

Comment: Interesting, and definitelyy noted for futire reference, but in this case, I don't want "anything goes", I do want a fixed, defined schema.

Answer (score 1):

It is my understanding that Mongoose Schema does not support arrays of this nature. You can only define one item type.

Is this structure going to be consistent across all documents you insert? i.e. codecs of length 2, the first with layers & the second without? If so, you could rearrange the schema into separate fields, layered & non-layered codecs. Each could then have its own schema matching that shown. Incoming objects can then be coerced predictably into this format.

Otherwise, you can just define one codec element type, with all possible fields for an element.

Comment: Excellent point. At the moment, yes, the structure is as above. What future variants we might have to cater for is as yet uncertain (it's very much v 0.1 right now!). My background is actually in traditional relational databases, where I woudl definitely take exactly the approach you described. I haven't gone that way here (yet) because we've got nice CRUD base classes / boilerplate /components, so I was hoping to get a free ride.

Comment: It's often the appeal of NoSql that it does allow flexibility (with tradeoffs later on). The relational approach enforces data-structure decisions earlier. One advantage of Mongo/Mongoose is that you can add fields to your schema with little friction as you go. Or of course you could use the `Mixed` schema type, and your base CRUD classes can store all data passed in by the user.